# How to implement GenericDAO class on Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, generics

I want UserDao class to extend GenericDAO where i'll have all CRUD methods. I have read article from IBM: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-genericdao/index.html , but i could not implement it. Could someone show me example based on my custom UserDao class.

```
@Transactional(value="myTransactionManager")
public class UserDao {

    @Qualifier("mySessionFactory")
    public SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public List<UserEntity> getAll() {
        Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(
                "from UserEntity ");
        List<UserEntity> userList = query.list();
        return userList;
    }

    public void updaet(UserEntity userEntity) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(userEntity);
    }

    public void delete(UserEntity userEntity) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(userEntity);
    }

    public void save(UserEntity userEntity) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(userEntity);
    }

}
```

i tried to write class like this

```
public class GenericDao{

    @Qualifier("mySessionFactory")
    public SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public <T> List<T> getAll(Class<T> t) {
        Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(
                "from " + t.getName());
        List<T> list = query.list();
        return list;
    }

    public <T> void save(T t) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(t);
    }

    public <T> void update(T t) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(t);
    }

    public <T> void delete(T t) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(t);
    }
}
```

but when i try to pull data with UserDao like this:

```
public List<UserEntity> getAll() {
    List<UserEntity> list = UserDao.findAll();
}
```

Eclipse IDE for line `List<UserEntity> list = UserDao.findAll();` give error : The method `findAll()` is underfined for type UserDao.

Comment: You need to pass the type to GenericDao, `GenericDao<T>` and extends it, obviously...

Comment: `UserDao`does not extend `GenericDao`You not add the generics to the class definition. `GenericDao <T, PK extends Serializable>`

Comment: UserDao does not extend GenericDao in description. But when i extend it gives error as described.

Comment: I was implemented as per your requirement : https://github.com/srinivas1918/spring4-and-hibernate4/blob/master/src/main/java/com/macsof/dao/AbstracDao.java

Answer (score 1):

this is my implementation :

GenericDao :

```
@Repository
public class GenericDao<T extends DbObject> {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Class<T> getParameterizedClass() {
        return (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    public T findById(final Serializable id) {
        return (T) getCurrentSession().get(getParameterizedClass(), id.toString());
    }

    public void persist(final T object) {
        getCurrentSession().persist(object);
    }

    public void saveOrUpdate(final T object) {
        getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(object);
    }

    public void delete(final T object) {
        getCurrentSession().delete(object);
    }

    public T merge(final T object) {
        return (T) getCurrentSession().merge(object);
    }

}
```

UserDao :

```
public class UserDao extends GenericDao<User> {

}
```

Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "...")    
public class User extends DbObject {
}
```

Comment: what this method for:
    private Class<T> getParameterizedClass() {
        return (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }